# Interacting with shell program in C to feed a custom Buffer into its gets() function (and more)

Tags: c, ipc, pipe, popen, buffer-overflow

If you dont want the long sschpeal head the the last paragraph-->

I found a buffer overflow vulnerability in a program that is using `gets()` to fill a function's local 1024-char* buffer. It's on **Sparc Solaris 5.8 (sun4u) 32-bit**.

The first obstacle to overcome was the `tch` was not letting me manually input > 257 chars
(256 if I want to be able to hit enter ;)

To bypass this, I have been executing `/bin/sh` and `stty raw` and I can effectively overflow the buffer now with > 1095 chars. 
(Note : I have to use Ctrl-J to do line-feeds/enter , though I haven't researched stty raw to examine why this change occurs.

**My issue is this**: it is now time to not only overflow the buffer but also write new return address / preserve %fp in ***hex codes***. But since I know of no way to manually enter hex codes from inside a terminal program, I figured I could find a way to use C and have it execute/interact with the vulnerable program and eventually send it my custom buffer.

HOWEVER, if I had a way to manually enter / copy paste hex bytes, I could just do something EASY like this!!!

```
perl -e 'print "n" . "A"x1094 . "\xff\xbe\xf5\x58" . "\xff\xbe\xff\x68" . "\0"'
```

(if you're wondering why I am printing 'n' it is because the vulnerable program checks for a yes/no @ index 0 of the string)

because I know no way to manually paste such hex-information, I have been trying in C.
In C, I craft the special buffer and have been learning to `popen()` the vulnerable program ("w") and fputs my buffer, but it has been working iffy at best. (popen and `IPC` is all new to me)

(I also tried `piping/dup2ing` and i got NO results, no evidence of effective string output/input) not sure what is going wrong, and I experimented much with the code and later abandoned it.

The best to depict the output from my 'popen' program is that there is a segfault in the vulnerable program only by delimiting the buffer at indexes [1096->1099], this is effectively the location of the function's `%fp`, so it seemed normal @ **first**. However, delimiting the string at indexes HIGHER than this leaves the programing working fine (WTF)!!! And that sort of behavior makes me think WTF!!? That is not the same behavior as manually pasting,  as going more chars most definitely changes seg fault -> bus error, *because I will be next overwriting the return address* followed by whatever possibly important info in that *stack frame* and beyond!!

Is the whole string not actually getting sent in one bang?!?!? I heard something about buffer `fflush()` issues from the `popen() manpage`, but I dont understand that talk!!

It's my first time using `popen()`, and there is more behavior that I have deemed strange-> if i stop `fputs()`ing data , the vulnerable program goes into an infinite loop, repeatedly printing the last output string that it NORMALLY would 
only print once, 
but in this case, whenever i stop fputs'ing, the thing starts infinitely printing out. Now, I expected that if I am not outputting, wouldn't the program just sit and wait for more input like a good duck. ??? apparently not. apparently it has to keep on pissing and moaning that I need to enter the next string!! is this normal behavior with popen?! Perhaps it is due to my popen' program exiting and closing with pclose(), before actually finishing (but i was expecting a buffer overflow and i dont know why I am not getting it like I could when pasting manually)

**Note**: I am using "\r\n" to signal the vulnerable program to do a 'return' , I am not sure the equivalent of CTRL-J / Enter key (which enter key does not work in raw tty). I am also not sure if raw tty is even necessary when piping a buffer.

then I thought I try to be clever and cat the strings to a file and then do a pipe via command line. I have no idea if u can pipe like this to a program expecting inputs
*in this form, I could not even get a single overflow!!* i.e.

```
printf "\r\n" > derp && perl -e 'print "n" . "A"x1025' >> derp && printf "\r\n" >> derp
cat derp | ./vuln
```

Now, rewind <-> back in tsh, i said I have a 257 char limit, and i needed to do ONE LESS THAN THAT if i wanted to be able to hit enter and have the program continue operation. So, perhaps \r\n is not right here, cause that's 2 chars. either that or you just Cannot `cat` into a program like this. But I AM using \r\n in my C programs to tell the vulnerable program that I have hit enter, and they are at least mildly more functional (not really), though still not overflowing the buffer in the same fashion as manually pasting my trash buffer.

ARGh!!!

Also, using just one or the other: '\r' or '\n' was most definitely not working! is there another control char out there I am missing out on? And is it possible that this could be one of my issues with my programs???

but basically my whole problem is I cant' seem to understand how to create a program to run and interface with a command-line executable and say hey!!! Take this whole buffer into your gets(), i know you'd really love it!! just as I would if I was running the program from terminal myself.
And i know of no way to manually paste / write hex codes into the terminal, **is the whole reason** why i am trying to write an interacting program to
craft a string with hext bytes in C and send to that program's gets()!!!!
If you jumped to this paragraph, i want you also to know that I am using specifically /bin/bash and stty raw so that I could manually input more than 257 chars (not sure if I NEED to continue doing this if I can successfully create an interacting program to send the vulnerable program the buffer. maybe sending a buffer in that way bypasses tch' terminal 257 char limit)

Can anyone help me!?!?!?!?!

Comment: Ah so confused - what on earth is a program's gets() ?  In my universe gets() is a function that allows you to read from stdin, and that function is well known to have some dangerous sides to it if used carelessly.

Comment: `gets` is buffered. There should be absolutely no difference as long as you are sending the same input. You should be able to write your exploit using hex editor and then pipe it (`<`) to this program.

Comment: Why is this problem interesting at all?   Solaris 5.8 is twelve years old now.

Comment: `pclose` will flush the output into the program you executed for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shell is reading with `gets()`, it is reading its standard input.

In your exploit code, therefore, you need to generate an appropriate overlong string.  Unless you're playing at being `expect`, you simply write the overlong buffer to a pipe connected from your exploit program to the victim's standard input.  You just need to be sure that your overlong string doesn't contain any newlines (CR or LF).  If you pipe, you avoid the vagaries of terminal settings and control-J for control-M etc; the pipe is a transparent 8-bit transport mechanism.

So, your program should:

1. Create a pipe (`pipe()`).
2. Fork.
3. Child:

   - connect the read end of the pipe to standard input (`dup2()`).
   - close the read and write ends of the pipe.
   - exec the victim program.
   - report an error and exit if it fails to exec the victim.
4. Parent:

   - close the read end of the pipe.
   - generates the string to overflow the victim's input buffer.
   - write the string to the victim down the pipe.
5. Sit back and watch the fireworks!

You might be able to simplify this with `popen()` and the `"w"` option (since the parent process will want to write to the child).

You might need to consider what to do about signal handling.  There again, it is simpler not to do so, though if you write to a pipe when the receiver (victim) has exited, you will get a SIGPIPE signal which will terminate the parent.

Answer (score 2):

The `popen` call is probably the call you want. Make sure to call `pclose` after the test is finished so that the child process is properly reaped.

**Edit** Linux man page mentioned adding "b" to the mode was possible for binary mode, but POSIX says anything other than "r" or "w" is undefined. Thanks to Dan Moulding for pointing this out.

```
FILE *f = popen("./vuln", "w");
fwrite(buf, size, count, f);
pclose(f);
```

Comment: `popen` accepts only `"r"` or `"w"` for the `mode` parameter. Any other values invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanMoulding: Thank you for pointing this out! Edit has been made, regards

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is yielding results.

Let me make highlights of what I suspect are issues.
the string that I pipe includes a `\n` at the beginning to acknowledge the "press enter to continue" of the vulnerable program.

The buffer I proceed to overflow is declared `char c[1024]`; now I fill this up with over 1100 bytes. I don't get it; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Wavering factor is if I am in gdb (being in gdb yields better results). but sometimes it doesn't overflow there either. DUE TO THIS, I really believe this to be some sort of issue with the shell / terminal settings on how my buffer is getting transferred.  But I have no idea how to fix this :(

I really appreciate the help everybody. But I am not receiving consistent results. I have done a number of things and have learned a lot of rough material, but I think it might be time to abandon this effort. Or, at least wait longer until someone comes through with answers.

p.s.
installed Expect, :) but I could not receive an overflow from within it...

I seemed to necessitate Expect anyways, because after the pipe is done doing its work I need to regain control of the streams. Expect made this very simple, aside from that fact that I can't get the program to overflow.

I swear this has to do something with the terminal shell settings but I don't have a clue.

Comment: 1100 bytes isn't much of a safety margin (overkill margin) for a 1024 byte buffer.  Send 2000 or even 4000 characters; see whether that kills it reliably.

Comment: If it is a terminal settings issue, then you probably need to drive the victim via a pseudo-tty or `pty`.  This is what `expect` does.  Note that if you have to do this, the program is much less readily exploitable than it seems at first sight.

Comment: Okay, I've been slow on the uptake. Are you certain that the inconsistent behavior is not due to the program sometimes taking a different code path that leads you to a different `gets` call using a different buffer?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I posted an update based on using a wicked large buffer. see those *Strange* results. (posted currently* at the bottom of this question's main page)

Comment: @user315052 Yes I am 100% positive. well you do make me wonder. This strange behavior makes me not want to be so conclusive. So I wonder... but i am mostly pretty darn sure. No different code path, GDB has been pretty sure of that as well :) but geeze u make me wonder if i should be more strict to truly ensure that

Answer (score 0):

## Another update

It's teh strangest.

I have actually effectively overwritten the return address with the address of a shellcode environment variable.

That was last night, Oddly enough, the program crashed after going to the end of the environment variable, and never gave me a shell. The shellcode is handwritten, and works (in an empty program that alters main's return address to the addr of the shellcode and returns, simply for test purposes to ensure working shellcode). In this test program Main returns into my SPARC shellcode and produces a shell.

...so.... idk why it didn't work in the new context. but thats the least of my problems. because the overflow it's strange.....

I couldn't seem to reproduce the overflow after some time, as I had stated in my prior post. So, i figured hey why not, let's send a bigger,more dangerous 4000 char buffer filled with trash "A"s like @JonathanLeffler recommended, to ensure segfaulting. And ok let's just say STRANGE results.

If I send less than 3960 chars, there will NOT be an overflow (WTF?!?!), although *earlier* i could get overflow at times when doing only about 1100 chars, which is significantly less, and that smaller buffer would overwrite the exact spot of return address (when it worked .**cough*)

### NOW THE strangest part!!!

this 'picky' buffer seems to segfault only for specific lengths. But i tried using gdb after sending the big 4000 char buffer, and noticed something strange. Ok yes it segfaulted, but there were 'preserved areas,' including the return address i previously was able to overflow, is somehow unharmed, and u can see from the [image](http://s16.postimage.org/4l5u9g3c3/Screen_shot_2012_06_26_at_11_29_38_PM.png) (**DONT CLICK IT YET**) Read the next paragraph to understand everything so u can properly view it. I am sure it looks a mess without proper understanding. parts of my crafted buffer are not affecting certain areas of memory that I have affected in the past with a smaller buffer! How or why this is happening. I do not know yet. I have no idea how regular this behavior is. but i will try to find out .

That image takes place about 1000 bytes in from the buffer's start address. you can see the 'preserved memory segments', embedded between many 0x41's from my buffer ("A" in hex) . In actuality, address 0xffbef4bc holds the return address of 0x0001136c, which needs to be overwritten, it is the return address of the function that called this one, 'this one' = the function that holds the vulnerable buffer. we cannot write **(**the function that vulnerable buffer belongs to***)*'s return address due to the nature of stack windows in SPARC -- that return address is actually BELOW the address of the buffer, unreachable, so therefore we must overwrite the return address of the function above us. aka our caller ;)

Anyways the point is that I was also able to previously overflow that return address sometimes with a smaller buffer. So WTF is up with these gaps!!?!??! Shouldnt a larger buffer be able to overflow these, esp. if the smaller buffer could (though not consistently).. Whatever, here's the image.

[image] http://s16.postimage.org/4l5u9g3c3/Screen_shot_2012_06_26_at_11_29_38_PM.png

Comment: How do you know that the return address is always in the stack? Wouldn't sparc sometimes store return address in a register?

Comment: @user315052 
The return address in question will always be in i7, i7 along with all registers are a part of the stack frame/window. in sparc, for every function call, a new window is made that sets space for all the registers in the stack at the very least. 

for every time I have debugged with gdb, the return address and its value has been consistent as well. I check the address of the function's and values located in i7. both through the stack pointer and with 'info reg'